# Handle form props of a redux-form stylised with material-ui

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, material-ui, redux-form

I'm trying to create a login form that makes a API call who returns a token. 
I'm new with react and redux so to do that I followed [this tutorial](http://blog.slatepeak.com/build-a-react-redux-app-with-json-web-token-jwt-authentication/).

The login form is a redux-form.
Here is the code :

**login.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';  
import { connect } from 'react-redux';  
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';  
import { loginUser } from '../../actions/index';

const form = reduxForm({  
  form: 'login'
});

class Login extends Component {  
  handleFormSubmit(formProps) {
    this.props.loginUser(formProps);
  }

  renderAlert() {
    if(this.props.errorMessage) {
      return (
        <div>
          <span><strong>Error!</strong> {this.props.errorMessage}</span>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { handleSubmit } = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this))}>
        {this.renderAlert()}
        {/* {this.renderAlert.bind(this)} */}
          <div>
            <label>Username</label>
            <Field name="username" component="input" type="text" />
          </div>
          <div>
            <label>Password</label>
            <Field name="password" component="input" type="password" />
          </div>
          <button type="submit">Login</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {  
  return {
    errorMessage: state.auth.error,
    message: state.auth.message
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { loginUser })(form(Login));
```

When the form is submitted, the props ({username, password}) are passed to HandleFormSubmit and then to loginUser function who is a redux action created to call the login API.
That worked perfectly but now I'm trying to integrate Material Ui to stylised the fields of the form.

```
// input basic version
<Field name="username" component="input" type="text" />
// material-ui version 
<Field name="username" component={TextField} type="text" />
```

With this change the props username and password are not passed to handleFormSubmit function so I can't realize a correct API call to login the user.
So I need your help to fix this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to introduce a translation layer from the props `redux-form` provides to the `material-ui` component.  This is covered in the `redux-form` docs [here](https://redux-form.com/7.1.2/examples/material-ui/).

For a `TextField` this would look like this:

```
const renderTextField = ({
  input,
  label,
  meta: { touched, error },
  ...custom
}) => (
  <TextField
    hintText={label}
    floatingLabelText={label}
    errorText={touched && error}
    {...input}
    {...custom}
  />
)
```

Then you pass this as the component to the `Field`:

```
<Field name="username" component={renderTextField} />
```

There is also a library that already has most of the wrappers you could need that you can just `import` and use just as you did called [redux-form-material-ui](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form-material-ui).